# gathering strings from columns and awd/sed print range of numeric values to generate text

Tags: bash, sed, awk

```
$ cat /etc/release
                  Solaris 10 10/09 s10s_u8wos_08a SPARC

$ cat test.txt|grep BTTR3
TTM2-0        1 XM-0-0-2    15BTR4  BTTR3-480&&-487            5
                            2BTR4   BTTR3-64&&-75              6
                            31BTR4  BTTR3-992&&-1023           7
                            21BTR4  BTTR3-672&&-703            8
                            29BTR4  BTTR3-928&&-959            9
                            37BTR4  BTTR3-1184&&-1215         10
                            27BTR4  BTTR3-864&&-895           11
                            12BTR4  BTTR3-384&&-415           17
                            5BTR4   BTTR3-160&&-191           18
                            34BTR4  BTTR3-1088&&-1119         19
                            18BTR4  BTTR3-576&&-607           20
                            35BTR4  BTTR3-1120&&-1151         21
                            40BTR4  BTTR3-1280&&-1311         22
                            24BTR4  BTTR3-768&&-799           23
```

I need to list and separate ranges which I have edited to make much smaller ranges, compared to real ranges (hundreds if not thousands of entries)
cat|awk '{print $2, $3} and then sed  on BTTR3 (string) would work to generate list of range if TTM2-0 weren´t together with first line of columns.

I would need something like this:

```
$ cat expected.txt
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-480
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-481
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-482
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-483
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-484
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-485
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-486
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-487
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-64
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-65
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-66
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-67
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-68
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-69
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-70
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-71
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-72
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-73
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-74
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-75
```

etc...

to later on remove first line of each generated range of thousands:

```
$ cat filtered.txt
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-481
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-482
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-483
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-484
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-485
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-486
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-487
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-65
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-66
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-67
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-68
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-69
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-70
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-71
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-72
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-73
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-74
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-75

$ echo "any help is"; /usr/bin/banner "VERY" ; echo "appreciated"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, the following script does what you want:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

with script.awk:

```
!/^ /{
    var1=$1
    var2=$4
    var3=$5
}
/^ /{
    var2=$1
    var3=$2
}
{
    split(var3, arr, "[-&]")
    for (i=arr[2]+1; i<=arr[5]; i++)
        print var1, var2, arr[1]"-"i
}
```

If the line does *not* start with a space, we set `var1`, `var2` and `var3`, if it starts with a space we set only `var2` and `var3` (change the variable names yourself, since I don't know what they refer to I used the generic name of `var1`). Then we further split `var3` and perform a loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep BTTR3 test.txt | 
nawk '
    function print_range(a, b, c,    d,i) {
        split(c, d, /&?&?-/)
        for (i = d[2]+1; i <= d[3]; i++) 
            printf "%s\t%s\t%s-%d\n", a,b,d[1],i
    } 
    NR==1 {a=$1; print_range(a, $4, $5); next} 
    {print_range(a, $1, $2)}
'
```

produces

```
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-481
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-482
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-483
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-484
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-485
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-486
TTM2-0  15BTR4  BTTR3-487
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-65
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-66
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-67
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-68
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-69
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-70
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-71
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-72
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-73
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-74
TTM2-0  2BTR4   BTTR3-75
TTM2-0  31BTR4  BTTR3-993
TTM2-0  31BTR4  BTTR3-994
TTM2-0  31BTR4  BTTR3-995
...
TTM2-0  24BTR4  BTTR3-797
TTM2-0  24BTR4  BTTR3-798
TTM2-0  24BTR4  BTTR3-799
```